# IndexError: list index out of range, When I run two python scripts at the same time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

I want to crawl data from a website, which is sorted by different province. To be faster, I try to run two or more python scripts to crawl each province at the same time. The only difference between two scripts is they crawl different url sets. Every time they worked well at the first 30 seconds or 1 minute. But later I got the below error in each script, and they arised simultaneously every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EOLGrades-A.py", line 157, in <module>
    dealEachCollege(url_2,tableName2,cNameList[i])
  File "EOLGrades-A.py", line 58, in dealEachCollege
    insertData(getData(sp),tableName,collegeName)
  File "EOLGrades-A.py", line 33, in getData
    if FAtd[x+j].text == '--' or FAtd[x+j].text ==' ':
IndexError: list index out of range

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EOLGrades-B.py", line 157, in <module>
    dealEachCollege(url_2,tableName2,cNameList[i])
  File "EOLGrades-B.py", line 58, in dealEachCollege
    insertData(getData(sp),tableName,collegeName)
  File "EOLGrades-B.py", line 33, in getData
    if FAtd[x+j].text == '--' or FAtd[x+j].text ==' ':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My getData Method:

```
def getData(soup,count):
    FAtr = soup.find_all(name='tr')
    FAtd = soup.find_all(name='td')
    m = [([0] * 6) for i in range(count)]
    x = 0
    if(len(FAtd)<=1):
        print("no data")
        return ['0']
    else:      
        for i in range(count):
            for j in range(6):
                if FAtd[x+j].text == '--' or FAtd[x+j].text ==' ':
                    m[i][j] = None
                else:
                    content = FAtd[x+j].text.strip()
                    m[i][j] = content           
            x= x+6
    return m
```

count is from getCount Method:

```
def getCount(soup):
    FAtr = soup.find_all(name='tr')
    count = len(FAtr) - 1
    return count
```

dealEachCollege Method:

```
def dealEachCollege(URL,tableName,collegeName):
    page = s.get(URL,headers=headers)
    page.encoding='utf-8'
    sp = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")
    count = getCount(sp)
    insertData(getData(sp,count),tableName,collegeName,count)
    page.close()
```

insertData Method:

```
def insertData(dataList,tableName,collegeName,count):
    try:
        m=dataList
        if m[0]=='0':
            return
        for i in range(count):
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(collegeName,m[i][0],m[i][1],m[i][2],m[i][3],m[i][4],m[i][5]))
            conn.commit() 
        print ("Successfully inserted into %s." %tableName)
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print ("Mysql Error %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
```

The error didn't arise when I just ran one single script.
Could anybody tell me how to fix it? Or any other methods to run 2 python crawlers at the same time? Many thanks!

Comment: can't use `list.append(data)` instead of `list[i] = data` ?why do you know that there is always count*6 elements ? it seems page gives you less elements. Print page.text to see what you get - or write in file and open in text editor or inweb browser. Maybe you get warnning message because portal doesn't like scripts/bots.

Comment: `x= x+6` is causing the `IndexError`.

Comment: @furas When I run only one script, it works perfectly. So I guess the problem focusing on what's wrong when two crawlers run simultaneously.

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma But why it works perfectly when I run only one script?

Comment: @ZezhongYu Try using `Lock`

Comment: print page.text and see what you get and maybe it gives answer for this problem. Maybe you see error message, or warning from server because it has no time to send correct data.